# Prepros ftp upload timeout

Tags: prepros

Im using prepros premium, and i'm having a issue where after 1-2 saves, prepros times out, and can't upload the files to the server using ftp.

I've tried to

- Put Keep Alive Timeout down to 1000.
- Restart it and Reinstall it.

Any suggestions.?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to enable "Reuse connection" to prevent a disconnect/connect action for each save. Perhaps the server doesn't like that many connections shortly after another.